# Adding Emulator in Eclipse for j2me application

Tags: java-me

Hi I am developing application in android . But I am new to develop J2ME Application .I have a doubt that where will be emulator available to run the application .I mean that where can i download the emulator and where can i install .Pls Help me

Answer (score 2):

To build an application in android you do not require J2ME but Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download [WTK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) and install it. Then you can set up WTK Emulator as external tool in Eclipse to run your application. But there is a version of Eclipse for mobile application development: [Eclipse Pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/). It will much easier to use Pulasr instead of setting usual version of Eclipse.